# adding Page TSconfig via ext_localconf.php seems different to adding it in the backend in the page resources (TYPO3 9 LTS)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

in my sitepackage i am adding page TSconfig via ext_localconf.php:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
     '<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Configuration/PageTS/tsconfig.typoscript">'
);
```

In this file i load other typoscript files depending on page ids:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Site/abc/PageTS/tsconfig.typoscript" condition="[9298 in tree.rootLineIds]">
```

For most features this concept works - but not for all:

This file contains a TCEFORM definition for AspectRatios:

```
TCEFORM.sys_file_reference.crop.config.cropVariants {
    desktop-wide {
       title = Desktop (1471 - 1920px)
       selectedRatio = 16:9
       allowedAspectRatios {
   etc ...
```

I can see the definition in the page module info but it does not work. When i open a content element with an image my definitions are not there.

But when i load the same file not via ext_localconf.php but manually in the page properties of my root page in the backend:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:sitepackage/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Site/abc/PageTS/tsconfig.typoscript">
```

it works as expected, the aspect ratios are there.

I am a bit puzzled why this happens - the info module shows that the file is loaded but it simply not works.

Any ideas why this happens and how i could work around it without loading the file manually in the page properties?

Comment: Have you tried it without condition? I'm not sure if the image-/file-layer hat a page UID and the condition can match.